# ArrayList dando erro

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Estou fazendo um programinha com banco de dados e nao estou conseguindo fazer com que a minha lista apareça em um `jtable`. Eu criei o método e na hora que eu chamo o meu método ele da erro, alguém pode me ajudar o código esta ai embaixo?

Erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at apresentacao.TelaCliente.formInternalFrameOpened(TelaCliente‌​.java:593)

Método da lista

```
public List<cliente>preencherTabela(){
        String sql = "select * from cliente";
        cliente c=new cliente();

        List<cliente> lista = new ArrayList<>();

         try(PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)){

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                c.setIdcodigo(rs.getInt("idcodigo"));
                c.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                c.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                c.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                c.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
                c.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                c.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                c.setCelualr(rs.getString("celular"));
                c.setCep(rs.getString("cep"));
                c.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
                c.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
                c.setDatanascimento(rs.getString("datanascimento"));
                c.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
                c.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
            }
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario nao encontrado" + ex);
        }
        return lista;
    }
}
```

codigo pra chamar o metodo

```
private void formInternalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                         
        cliente c = new cliente();
        List<cliente> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Conexao con=null;
        lista=con.preencherTabela();

        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            c=lista.get(i);
            jPcad.setValueAt(c.getIdcodigo(), i, 0);
            jPcad.setValueAt(c.getNome(), i, 1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Há vários problemas nesse código. Um dos problemas é que você está retornando uma lista vazia, pois o método `preencheTabela()` cria objetos advindos do banco, mas jamais são adicionados a lista. Adicione um `lista.add(c)`no fim do `while`:

```
public List<cliente> preencherTabela(){
        String sql = "select * from cliente";
        cliente c=new cliente();

        List<cliente> lista = new ArrayList<>();

         try(PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql)){

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                c.setIdcodigo(rs.getInt("idcodigo"));
                c.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                c.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                c.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                c.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
                c.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                c.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                c.setCelualr(rs.getString("celular"));
                c.setCep(rs.getString("cep"));
                c.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
                c.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
                c.setDatanascimento(rs.getString("datanascimento"));
                c.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
                c.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                lista.add(c);
            }
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario nao encontrado" + ex);
        }
        return lista;
    }
}
```

Outro problema é que você atribui `null` a conexão com o banco logo antes de chamar o método acima:

```
private void formInternalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                         
        cliente c = new cliente();
        List<cliente> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Conexao con=null;
        lista=con.preencherTabela();

        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            c=lista.get(i);
            jPcad.setValueAt(c.getIdcodigo(), i, 0);
            jPcad.setValueAt(c.getNome(), i, 1);
        }

}
```

Sem conexão, `con.preencherTabela();` não vai funcionar, vai estourar `nullpointerexception`. Inicie a conexão para que a lista possa ser retornada.

Comment: Precisa de um espaço entre o tipo de retorno e o nome do método": public List<cliente> preencherTabela() {

Comment: @n3uRoQuiLa isso deve ser sido erro na hora de copiar aqui no site, senão o código dele nem iria compilar e estourar o nullpointerexception na linha informada.

Comment: Com certeza, foi só uma sinalização mesmo.

Comment: como faço para arrumar isso, eu nao consegui, pode me ajudar!!!

Comment: @ThiJoe basta fazer as alterações sugeridas na resposta.

Comment: eu fiz, mais nao deu, vc pode mostrar por favor!!!

Comment: @ThiJoe que problema ocorre?

Comment: ele nao ocorre nenhum erro agora, mais quando eu inicializo o meu programa , era pra carregar as listas no tabela , mais nao aparece

Comment: @ThiJoe ai já é outro problema diferente da sua pergunta original. Seria interessante encerrar essa aceitando a resposta, clicando em `v` e criar uma nova pergunta com esta nova duvida, colocando o link dessa aqui como referencia.

Comment: valeu irmao , desculpa a demora por responder , estou muito atarefado e tenho pouco tempo de respoder , valeu irmão